# Does the position of an object on a scale change the measurement of weight? If so why does this happen?

Tags: measurements

After weighing the same object on the same scale, it seemed like the location of the object on the scale changed the weight of the object. I tried googling for the reason why this happened but couldn't find anything related to this topic.

I did find this
[Why does the scale reading depend on the position of the object on the scale and how to equalize that?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309657/why-does-the-scale-reading-depend-on-the-position-of-the-object-on-the-scale-and)
but I would like to do some more reading on this topic. Where can I find some more trustable information on this matter?

Comment: Similar concept  [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276642/which-force-does-a-weighing-scale-measure#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=Generally%2C%20a%20scale%20will%20measure,the%20weight%20of%20the%20object.)

Answer (score 1):

weighing devices that use electronic strain gauges under the weighing pan are usually designed in such a way that the weighing electronics can detect an off-center placement of the object to be weighed by comparing the outputs of several different strain gauges at the corners of the device, and still deduce its correct weight.

The more expensive the weighing device, the better it can compensate in this way for off-centered loads. Electronic scales for industrial use will commonly specify the load positioning limits on the weighing platform, inside of which the device will meet its stated accuracy specifications.

This is a pretty specialized topic and you might be best served by studying the design documentation on the websites of companies that make these devices.